# CakePHP bizarre saveAll issue. Returns true, but nothing in database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, save, has-many

I have two models, `Statement` -> hasMany -> `LineItem`.

I'm passing the following array to `$this->saveAll()` inside one of `Statement`'s methods:

```
$data = array(
    'Statement' => array(
        'employee_id' => 1
    ),
    'LineItem' => array(
        0 => array('job_id' => 1),
        1 => array('job_id' => 9),
        2 => array('job_id' => 12),
    )
);
```

`$this->saveAll($data) == true`, but when I check the `statements` table in the database, it is empty.  The strange bit?  The auto_increment `id` column has been incremented by 1.  This is also reflected by the fact that `$this->Statement->id` matches the current auto_increment of the table.

All of the above is true for the `line_items` table as well, only the auto_increment has been incremented by 3.

### **Update**

When using `$this->save($data)`, the Statement is saved correctly (of course, without the `LineItem` records).  So, what's up with saveAll?

### **Update**

So, I suppose the problem is somewhere in my controller or model.  Some stupid *doh!* moment I'm sure.  Here is the code from my controller and my model (comments and unrelated code removed for brevity).

First, the model:

```
class Statement extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('CompanyStatement', 'Employee');
    public $hasMany = array('LineItem');
    public $name = 'Statement';

    public function build_statement($data = NULL) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            if ($this->saveAll($data)) {
                $result = array(
                    'message' => 'Statement was saved.',
                    'element' => 'flash_success',
                    'success' => TRUE
                );
            } else {
                $result = array(
                    'message' => 'There was a problem saving.',
                    'element' => 'flash_error',
                    'success' => FALSE
                );
            }
        } else {
            $result = array(
                'message' => 'No data was received.',
                'element' => 'flash_error',
                'success' => FALSE
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
 class StatementsController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Statements';

    public function create_new_statement() {
        $result = $this->Statement->build_statement($this->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash($result['message'], $result['element']);
        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'statements',
            'action' => 'edit',
            $this->Statement->id
        ));
    }
    public function edit($id = NULL) {
        $this->set('statement' => $this->Statement->findById($id));
    }
 }
```

The LineItem model is very concise:

```
class LineItem extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'LineItem';
    public $belongsTo = array('Statement', 'Job');
}
```

### Getting Somewhere

I turned off the redirect in the controller method, and took a look at the SQL dump:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row:
a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`line_items`,
CONSTRAINT `line_items_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`statement_id`) REFERENCES `statements` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

[CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 681]

Query: INSERT INTO `line_items` (`job_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (1, '2010-11-02 15:22:39', '2010-11-02 15:22:39') 
Query: INSERT INTO `line_items` (`job_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (9, '2010-11-02 15:22:39', '2010-11-02 15:22:39') 
Query: INSERT INTO `line_items` (`job_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (10, '2010-11-02 15:22:39', '2010-11-02 15:22:39')
```

The transaction is being rolled back.

So why isn't the `statement_id` being added to the query in the transaction when using saveAll?

Comment: What happens when you try to save it without the associated data?

Comment: I'll try and let you know in 5 minutes.

Comment: frameworks are infallible - user error suspected :P

Comment: @f00: Agreed... Also, I'm using saveAll in another part of the application without fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Cake will expect the foreign key on line_items to be statement_id. You haven't shown the table structures. Is there actually a column statement_id on line_items?

Comment: Yes.  `line_items` has the following columns: `id int(10)`, `statement_id int(10)`, `job_id int(10)`, `created datetime`, and `modified datetime`.

Comment: And the winner is....  Leo!  I had a typo in my columns.  In the line_items table, the column `statement_id` was erroneously named `statment_id`.  I knew it was a *Doh!* moment.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's the story of my life!

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me every once in a while when I forget to commit transactions. Have you disabled autocommit? Are you using transactions? Did you forget to commit or tell cakePHP you needed to commit?

Comment: I want to believe it has something to do with transactions.  But CakePHP is supposed to handle transactions for me automatically when using the saveAll Method on InnoDB tables.  I've used it before without having to "commit" anything.

Comment: FYI - I dont use or know CakePHP, this just bites me every once in a while when I'm developing other apps. It might be worth checking into even if CakePHP is managing your transactions. The mysterious incrementing column  is a good sign something was rolled back.

Comment: Thanks bot403.  I'm becoming more certain that you are correct.  Let's assume the problem is not with CakePHP.  Both tables are currently empty.  What would cause a transaction to fail?

Comment: Not calling commit() for one ;) Exiting without calling commit will cause an automatic rollback. Uncaught foreign key errors would also cause it. Have you looked into your InnoDB logs? 'show engine status innodb' in mysql will give you some good insight into failed transactions.

Comment: Alright..  I've tracked the problem down to CakePHP not building my queries correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your interest/help.  Part of your answer is what led me down the path to enlightenment.  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->saveAll();
```

won't work, instead try:

```
$this->Statement->saveAll();
/* or */
$this->LineItem->saveAll();
```

Comment: What?  I'm in the `Statement` model.

Comment: It's far more usual to use the save methods in a controller, indeed the examples in the Book are all in the controller. As you didn't state you were doing this in a model, PawelMysior's comment is entirely valid. Have you tried doing this in a controller? It seems unlikely but, nevertheless, possible that the way the method is written expects that. +1 correction.

Comment: @Leo:  Your comment doesn't make any sense.  There is no save method that exists in the controller.  When you do something like `$this->Model->saveAll()` in the controller, you are still saving from the Model.  The cookbook examples are written for beginners to understand.  Trying to force the concept of skinny controllers would be beyond the scope of the documentation.  My second sentence indicates that I am in the `Statement` model.  This is obvious since the controller would be named `StatementsController`.  Furthermore, Pawel's statement "`$this->saveAll();` won't work" is 100% false.

Comment: If this question were re-worded to indicate that I should try to save the data using a model chain in a controller method instead of directly in a model method, it would contain fewer inaccuracies, but remain incorrect.

Comment: @stephen: Pawel's statement "$this->saveAll(); won't work" - that's because most people do this in the controller. My comment makes perfect sense. Your remarks about the second sentence would be true if naming conventions were rigourously applied in this forum - but they're not.

Comment: @Leo.  The fact that most people put all of their code in a fat controller doesn't make Pawels' statement true.  "I'm not sure I want popular opinion on my side -- I've noticed those with the most opinions often have the fewest facts." --Bethania McKenstry

Comment: Since you didn't state it clearly, I wrongly assumed that you did that in the controller, sorry about that. Well I just tried this with some models I have and it works. Post both models code, maybe I'll be able to notice something.

Comment: @Pawel:  Sure thing.  Sorry about hijacking your answer's comments to argue with Leo.

Comment: Well, try adding `Statement` to `public $belongsTo` array in the `LineItem` model, but I don't think that's (will work without it for me). I have no idea. In the model function, calling `pr($data)` just before `$this->saveAll()` prints out exactly like you wrote in the question?

Comment: Sorry, `EmployeeStatement` was a typo due to me cleaning up the code for posting here.  I fixed it.  I'll try your suggestion.